# In for loop, How to wait for a process to complete before jumping to next iteration? (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c

sample code :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)  
{  
    NSLog(@"%d Iteration started",i); 
   [[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:      ^(NSData * _Nullable data,        NSURLResponse * _Nullable response,        NSError * _Nullable error) {     
    NSLog(@"%d iteration completed ",i);  
    }] resume];
}
```

//Log inside the block should execute before moving to next iteration!

Comment: A very bad idea to perform data operation in a loop.

Comment: use recursion not just loop

Comment: As Lu_ just wrote, recursion is a good solution. To do async tasks in a loop... it is wrong. But if you want ... then use an index 'i' and a while loop with 'i < 5'. Increment the index in the completion block before exiting...

Comment: Recursion is not at all the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

A completion handler is exactly that; a handler that is called on completion of a task.

If you want the next task to kick off when the current task is complete, then trigger it from the completion handler.

```
[[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:      ^(NSData * _Nullable data,        NSURLResponse * _Nullable response,        NSError * _Nullable error) {     
    NSLog(@"%d iteration completed ",i);
    // kick off next request here.
}] resume];
```

Comment: If read question then there is clear requirements of synchronisation task by saying how to wait for a process before jumping to next iteration.

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya A completion block *is a synchronization primitive*. The completion block is called when the task is complete, not before.  Therefore, you use the completion block to (a) trigger updating of the UI based on the completed state and (b) trigger any new computation that can only be done on completion of the current task.

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya Part of OP's problem is using a `for()` loop at all;  a loop isn't necessary at all.